# How can you give a player a speed boost when they are sprinting in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a vanilla KitPvP server, and I want to make a kit that gives you normal *walking* speed, but when you are *sprinting*, you have a speed boost. Is that possible? If so, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add an objective to keep track of whether players are sprinting:

```
/scoreboard objectives add IsSprinting stat.sprintOneCm
```

On a clock, give all players with a score in that objective of at least 1 the speed effect:

```
/effect @a[score_IsSprinting_min=1] speed 1 2
```

Then, also on the same clock, set the score to 0 for everyone so that the speed boost stops being applied when a player stops sprinting:

```
/scoreboard players set @a IsSprinting 0
```

Comment: Awww, Colorfusion, you steal all the positions for my answers :D

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `minecraft.custom:minecraft.sprint_one_cm` instead of `stat.sprint_one_cm` and the middle command becomes `/effect give @a[scores={isSprinting=1..}] speed 1 2`